# generic: extends Number & Comparable Basic understanding

Tags: java, generics

```
class  MyTest<K,V extends Number & Comparable> implements Comparable<MyTest>{

    private K key;
    private V value;

}
```

What does this mean `K, V extends Number & Comparable`? In above statement `MyTest` is implementing a comparable interface, But I am not able to figure out `K,V` and why there is  Number & Comparable. k,v are not an interface. Can some one enlighten me on this.

Comment: Its a key, value pairs.

Comment: [Naming convention reference here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html); this will be helpful to you in the future.

Answer (score 6):

This class accepts two generic arguments, first of them is named as `K` (which is likely to be used as "key"), and the second of them is named as `V` (which is likely to be used as "value").

`V extends Number & Comparable` part means that the class accepts only those `V` values which both extend `Number` abstract class and implement `Comparable` interface. Examples of such classes are standard JDK `Integer`, `Float`, `Long`, `Double` or `BigInteger`. If you want to use your own class as `V`, you should extend `Number` and implement `Comparable` at the same time. No restriction for the `K` is applied: you may use any class for `K`. For example, this type is valid:

```
MyTest<String, Integer> myTest; // K = String, V = Integer
```

But this one will result in compilation error:

```
MyTest<Integer, String> myTest; // K = Integer, V = String, does not implement Number
```

Comment: Incidentally, the `V extends...` uses a raw type, which it probably shouldn't. It should be `V extends Number & Comparable<V>`

Comment: @yshavit, agreed. Also it should be `implements Comparable<MyTest<K, V>>`

Answer (score 0):

We can subtype a generic class or interface by extending or implementing it. The relationship between the type parameters of one class or interface and the type parameters of another are determined by the extends and implements clauses.

For example, ArrayList implements List that extends Collection, so ArrayList is a subtype of List and List is subtype of Collection.
Here K represents key and V represents value. then from your code the Java compiler replaces the  type parameter K with the Number and  V with the Comparable, as below code:

```
private Number key;
private Comparable value;
```